# Comparing 2 Decimal numbers in the format 1.0.1 with 1.0

Tags: c#, string, decimal

I need to compare two `string`s using c# which are in the format given below:

```
numbers.numbers[.numbers]*
```

E.g.

```
1.0
1.0.0
1.0.1
1.2.34.5
```

Please, notice that `1.0` should be equal to `1.0.0`, `1.00`, `1.000.0.00` etc.- trailing all-zeroes chunks *don't count*.

I try doing it with `Decimal`

```
string1 = "1.0";   
string2 = "1.0.1"; 

if (Convert.ToDecimal(string1) <= Convert.ToDecimal(string2))    
{
   // Perfom some logic
}
```

but failed: when I use `Convert.ToDecimal(string1)` it gives me

> Input string in improper format error.

Could anyone help me out in this.

Comment: what is `1.0.1`? If you ask someone to borrow you `1.0.1 $` how much would you expect to get?

Comment: Ok then how to compare such numbers?

Comment: First you have to define the sortorder. Depending from that, you can use a built in or a custom sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that you're looking for [Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) class, not `String`:

```
  Version v1 = new Version("1.0");
  Version v2 = new Version("1.0.1");

  if (v1 <= v2) {
    //TODO: Put relevant code here 
  }
```

**Edit:** In case of *custom logic*, i.e. `1.0 == 1.0.0 == 1.0.0.0 = ... = 1.000.00 = ...` you have to *implement* it, e.g.

```
private static string TrimVersion(string value) {
  string result = Regex.Replace(value, @"(\.0+)+$", "");

  if (result.Contains('.'))
    return result;
  else
    return result + ".0";
}

...

Version v1 = new Version(TrimVersion("1.0"));
Version v2 = new Version(TrimVersion("1.0.0"));

if (v1 <= v2) {
  //TODO: Put relevant code here 
}
```

Comment: Version I already tried. However it works fine or this scenario, but fails for below scenario,    string1 = 1.0       string2=1.0.0  . And we have if condition as if(string1 <= string2)

Comment: @Skyrim: what is the desired result for `"1.0"` and `"1.0.0"` comparison?

Comment: 1.0 and 1.0.0 should be considered as equal in the IF condition.

Comment: Thank you the Version logic Worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
string string1 = "1.0";
string string2 = "1.0.1";

var version1 = new Version(string1);
var version2 = new Version(string2);

var result = version1.CompareTo(version2);
```

Results will be

```
result = 1 - version1 is greater
result = -1 - version2 is greater
result = 0 - both are equal
```

Comment: Ok let me try this.

Comment: Will the above logic consider "1.0" and "1.0.0" as equal?

Comment: When working with version in your case "1.0" and "1.0.0" are not equal. What you would want to return?

Comment: Thank you the Version logic Worked.